# Pokedex project api react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I'm trying to learn, react us and try to load the API on my pokedex app. https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokedex/1/ I'm trying to load every pokemon on the ( pokemon_entries ) list, but I don't know how to do

I have already created the card of the different Pokemon and I had tried to load the List on my app

ListPokemon

```
import React from 'react';
import Loader from '../components/Loader';



class ListPokemon extends React.Component {
    state = {
        isLoading: false,
        data: [ ]

      };

    async componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({isLoading:true})
        const {name, url} = this.props;

        try {
            const response = await fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokedex/1/`);
            const json = await response.json();
            this.setState({data: json,isLoading:false})
            console.log({json})
          } catch (err){
            console.log(err.msg);
            this.setState({isLoading:false})
            throw err
        }
    }



    render() {
        const {isLoading,data} = this.state;
        return (
          <>
            <h1>Lorem</h1>
          {
            isLoading ?<Loader/> : <h1>{data.entry_number}</h1>
          }


          </>
        );
      }
    }


export default ListPokemon
```

DataPokemon :

```
import React from 'react';
import { Card,Container,Row,Col } from 'react-bootstrap';

const DataPokemon = props =>  {const { name } = props;


return(
    <Container>
  <Row>
  <Col xs={6}>
    <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
  <Card.Img variant="top" src="holder.js/100px180" />
  <Card.Body>
    <Card.Title>{name}</Card.Title>
    <Card.Text>

    </Card.Text>
    {/* <Button variant="primary">Go somewhere</Button> */}
  </Card.Body>
</Card>
</Col>
</Row>
</Container>
)
}





export default DataPokemon;
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the x and get more or less pokemons.

```
     const pokeArray = [];   

     for(let i=1; i<x; i++) {
              axios.get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${i}`).then(res => {
                pokeArray.push( {
                  id: i,
                  name: res.data.name,
                  photo: res.data['sprites']['front_default'],
                  hp: res.data['stats'][5]['base_stat'],
                  attack: res.data['stats'][4]['base_stat'],
                  defense : res.data['stats'][3]['base_stat'],
                } )
              })
            }
```